# Object parenting to Rigify

Tags: rigging, parent

What is the best way to parent armor to Rigify? Is it to the FK bone and have to constantly snap it back to the IK position, or is there a smarter solution?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rigify has a lot of control bones, including for IK and FK mechanisms. These bones ultimately control the deformation bones which in turn deform the mesh.

I would bind armor pieces to one of the deformation bones. You find them at [bone layer](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/properties/skeleton.html) 30. The names of all these bones start with the *DEF-* prefix. You can parent the armor mesh directly to the bone so it will move but not deform in an unnatural way.